# Installation of hplip 23.23.3 in ubuntu 23.04

Tags: printing

1. I did this:

   wget https://sourceforge.net/projects/hpl...3.run/download -O hplip-3.23.3.run
2. Then I did this:

   sudochmod +x hplip-3.23.3.run
3. Then

   sudo ./hplip-3.23.3.run

Then I got this message:

```
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency: libjpeg (libjpeg - JPEG library)
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency: libtool (libtool - Library building support services)
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency: cups-devel (CUPS devel- Common Unix Printing System development files)
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency: cups-image (CUPS image - CUPS image development files)
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency: gcc (gcc - GNU Project C and C++ Compiler)
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency: make (make - GNU make utility to maintain groups of programs)
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency: libpthread (libpthread - POSIX threads library)
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency: libusb (libusb - USB library)
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency: python3-devel (Python devel - Python development files)
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency: libnetsnmp-devel (libnetsnmp-devel - SNMP networking library development files)
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency: libcrypto (libcrypto - OpenSSL cryptographic library)
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency: python3-pyqt4 (PyQt 4- Qt interface for Python (for Qt version 4.x))
warning: This installer cannot install 'python3-pyqt4' for your distro/OS and/or version.
error: Installation cannot continue without this dependency. Please manually install this dependency and re-run this installer
```

How do you install this dependcies?

Is `sudo apt-get` command the way to do this?

thx for help

Comment: Is there some reason you can't do: `sudo apt update && sudo apt install hplip` ?

Comment: Missing REQUIRED dependency: libtool (libtool - Library building support services)
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency: python3-pyqt4 (PyQt 4- Qt interface for Python (for Qt version 4.x))
warning: This installer cannot install 'python3-pyqt4' for your distro/OS and/or version.
error: Installation cannot continue without this dependency. Please manually install this dependency and re-run this installer

Comment: installed that and ran installer. above is result. tried  using sudo apt-get for python3-pyqt4 and couln't install

Comment: ran this sudo apt install python3-pyqt4

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package python3-pyqt4 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python3-pyqt4' has no installation candidate